# Randomly select unique row from dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe of the form where `rn` is the row index

```
       A1  |  A2 |  A3 
      -----------------
r1     x   |  0  |  t
r2     y   |  1  |  u
r3     z   |  1  |  v
r4     x   |  2  |  w
r5     z   |  2  |  v
r6     x   |  2  |  w
```

If I wanted to subset this dataframe such that the column A2 has only unique values, I'd use `df.drop_duplicates('A2')`. However, that'd keep only the first row of the unique value and delete the rest. For this example, only r2 and r4 will be in the subset.

What I want is that any of the rows with duplicate values are selected randomly rather than the first row. So for this example, for `A2 == 1`, r2 or r3 is selected randomly or for `A2 == 2` any of r4, r5 or r6 is selected randomly. How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shuffle the DataFrame first and then drop the duplicates:

```
df.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates(subset='A2')
```

If the order of the rows is important you can use `sort_index` as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ suggested:

```
df.sample(frac=1).drop_duplicates(subset='A2').sort_index()
```

Comment: You'd typically want to sort the index after if you want to retain order.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sure. Let me add that.

Comment: Wow that was embarrassingly simple. Thanks.